# Three.js Texture scaling issue when using THREE.ShaderMaterial to map a renderTarget.texture to a quad

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

A codepen demonstrating this issue is here: https://codepen.io/lilrooness/pen/QWjdjgP

I'm rendering noise to a render target and then using that render target to texture a quad that I render to the screen.

When using the render target as a texure I'm encoutering a problem with the textures size.

It works fine if I use `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: renderTarget.texture })`

[image]

but when I use my own material

```
        var renderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: {
                tex: { type: 'sampler2D', value: renderTarget.texture }
            },
            fragmentShader: pixelateFragmentShader(),
            vertexShader: standardVertexShader()
        })
```

I get a very small texture that's clamped
[image]

This is the vertex shader that I use for both renders:

```
                varying lowp vec3 vUv;

                void main() {
                    vUv = position;
                    vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
                    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition; 
                }
```

this is the rendering function (im using the same camera to render both times)

```
        function animate() {
            time += 0.1;
            quad.material.uniforms.time.value = time;
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget);
            renderer.render(bufferScene, camera);
            renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
```

Again, this works fine if I use the MeshBasicMaterial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate the issue with a live example? Or maybe with a GitHub repository?

Comment: https://codepen.io/lilrooness/pen/QWjdjgP here is a codepen demonstrating the issue

Comment: There are many interesting things: using `PlaneGeometry()` (instead of `PlaneBufferGeoemtry()`), `position` as uv.

Comment: @manthrax - I don't want the texture repeated or clamped, I want it to be stretched to the same size as the quad it is rendered to

Comment: You're not getting your vUv from the geometry.. you're setting it from the position.. is that intentional?

Comment: THanks for the hint @prisoner849 - changed the vertex shader to use UV instaed of position and it started working. I'm new to this and I didn't realise UV was available to the vertext shader

Comment: @manthrax this was intentional for the perlin noise fragment shader, however I was re-suing the same vertex shader for the final render, and this was causing problems

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, in my vertex shader I was setting 
`vUv = position`

While this was desired behaviour for the perlin noise effect, I was re-using the same vertex shader to render the render target texture

I changed it to:
`vUv = uv;`